# Looking for setting which makes virtual user and samples count same in Blazemeter

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I just ran a simple load test on BlazeMeter with `4 virtual users` but after complete, I can see in request states `samples` not equal to no. of virtual users :

[image]

If we look at the above screenshot, It shows no. of samples. Do I need any specific setting in BlazeMeter to make my Samples count the same as no. of users?

I want to set like if I run test with `4 users` then I would see only `4 samples` per request in states. Because in actual it is sending 1 request per user as far as I understand.

Looks like I could not find where is the setting for `Loop Count` in BlazeMeter. I think Loop count can help me to get what I want but still looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems Blazemeter is showing the correct results, but you configured the test to run for more than 1 iteration.

If you are looking to run the test for a specific amount of iterations, go to test configuration and click on iterations (next to duration). This option will let you decide the number of iteration for each thread till the test stops instead of running the test for x minutes.

[image]

Comment: Cool. I simply could not notice that toggle for Duration and Iteration. Thanks for screenshot.